AVX2 consuming bytes whilst producing uints?
Slowly learning SIMD, but there are still some aspects that I cannot wrap my head around when trying to come up with SIMD solutions to a problem. One of those being when the input is smaller than the output.
As an example, lets say I have an 8 bit grayscale image. i.e each pixel is a byte in the range 0-255. And I now want to convert that to a pre-multiplied alpha image with a specified colour. So the input is an 8bit array (8 bit per pixel), but the output is a 32bit array (32 bit per pixel RGBA_8888).
So the arrays are not one to one. One byte in the grayscale array will be converted to 4 bytes in the colour array .
In scalar form, this would look like this :
 public class Test
 {
     const int ImageSize = 2048;
     const int ImageLength = ImageSize * ImageSize;
     private byte[] _bytesGray = new byte[ImageLength];
     private uint[] _pixelsRGBA = new uint[ImageLength];

     private const byte _colorR = 0xFF;
     private const byte _colorG = 0x01;
     private const byte _colorB = 0x02;
     private const byte _colorA = 0xFF;

     [GlobalSetup]
     public void Setup()
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < ImageLength; i++)
         {
             _bytesGray[i] = (byte)(i + 1);
             _pixelsRGBA[i] = 0;
         }
     }

     [Benchmark]
     public unsafe void GrayscaleToColor_Scalar()
     {
         fixed (byte* bytePtr = _bytesGray)
         fixed (uint* pixelPtr = _pixelsRGBA)
         {
             for (int i = 0; i < ImageLength; ++i)
             {
                 byte value = bytePtr[i];
                 byte r = (byte)((value * _colorR) >> 8);
                 byte g = (byte)((value * _colorG) >> 8);
                 byte b = (byte)((value * _colorB) >> 8);
                 byte a = (byte)((value * _colorA) >> 8);

                 pixelPtr[i] = (uint)(r << 24 | g << 16 | b << 8 | a);
             }
         }
     }
}

To process this in SIMD form, my thinking is that I want to process the _bytesGray array so I can take full advantage of the 256 vector register.
fixed (byte* valueBytes = _bytesGray)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ImageLength; i += 32)
    {
        ...
    }
}

But as the input pixel is a byte and the output pixel is a uint, I think I would then need 4x Vectors. Where each vector contains 8 of the 32 bytes. But each byte would then be duplicated 4 times in each uint. At which point I could then do my multiply
fixed (byte* valueBytes = _bytesGray)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ImageLength; i += 32)
    {
        Vector256<byte> bytes = Avx2.LoadVector256(valueBytes  + i);

        Vector256<uint> _0_8_grayBytes = ... // get 0-8 bytes and splat each byte to fill uint
        Vector256<uint> _8_16_grayBytes =  ... // get 8-16 bytes and splat each byte to fill uint
        Vector256<uint> _16_24_grayBytes =  ... // get 16-24 bytes and splat each byte to fill uint 
        Vector256<uint> _24_32_grayBytes =  ... // get 24-32 bytes and splat each byte to fill uint
    }
}

But I can't seem to figure out how to express what I want in instructions to do or even if its the right approach.
How would you go about doing this?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.intrinsics.vector256.asuint32?view=net-8.0#system-runtime-intrinsics-vector256-asuint32-1(system-runtime-intrinsics-vector256((-0)))'

You probably want to keep to change only one color.  So keep r and g constant and then take the grey scale and use value for b.

@DanielA.White that just reinterprets the data, I would actually need to move it around

A qword broadcast load (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpbroadcastb:vpbroadcastw:vpbroadcastd:vpbroadcastq) can feed a vpshufb using a control vector like _mm256_setr_epi32(0x00000000, 0x01010101, 0x02020202, ...) .  (It doesn't matter which copy of the byte you index; each half of the vector contains two copies of each input byte so the same index gets the same byte whether it's in the low or high 128-bit lane.)  That gets your data in place for further processing.  The high byte of the shuffle vec could be 0xFF to clear alpha, or you could OR something else into it.

Or you could vpmovzxbd to just zero-extend each byte to a u32, if that's more convenient for whatever you want to do next.  IIRC, C# has an intrinsic that takes a pointer for the source, unlike Intel's C/C++ intrinsic API where there's only one with a __m128i source and it's up to a compiler to fold an 8-byte zero-extending load intrinsic into a memory source operand for vpmovzx.

@PeterCordes I tried the shuffle and it works for the first half of the 256 value, but the second half has an implicit 16 added to the index, which means the second half is offset https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/cpp-compiler/developer-guide-reference/2021-8/mm256-shuffle-epi8.html

@creativergk: That's why you broadcast-load first, so source element i+16 is the same as element i in the broadcast result, so every result byte can find a copy of the byte it wants in the same the 128-bit lane.  (In fact only i%8 matters if you do an 8-byte vpbroadcastq.  Or you could do a 16-byte VBROADCASTI128 and shuffle it two different ways to get two 32-byte vectors from 16 source bytes.  BTW, the earlier link I included was accidentally for the AVX-512 version of the instruction; I meant to link https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpbroadcast for vpbroadcastq / vbroadcasti128.)

Ahh ok, so it will process 16 bytes at a time, not 32?

BTW you may try to do the multiplications with 16-bit elements, 32-bit is just overkill and (v)pmullw (or vpmulhuw if convenient) is (on Intel) more efficient than (v)pmulld, and you get twice the multiplications per instruction. It may cost extra shuffling or something, it's probably not just a free upgrade.

@creativergk: didn't see your reply right away since you didn't @ notify me.  Yeah, every 8 bytes of input turns into 32 bytes of output when going from 8-bit grayscale to RGBA.  The simplest way is to load 8 bytes at a time (in a way that's convenient for later shuffling, e.g. a broadcast-load), but broadcast-loading 16 bytes at a time to shuffle 2 ways and produce 2 vectors of output is probably more efficient.  On Intel (and AMD I think), broadcast-loads are as cheap as normal loads (https://uops.info/), so get some preliminary shuffling done for free, to set up for a cheap vpshufb.

Since you want to multiply each input, you might need to zero-extend bytes into 16-bit elements, maybe lined up inside the u32 element it will ultimately go into but in a vector with R and B elements, and another vector with G and A elements?  Maybe you can use vpmaddubsw to add results?  But no, to get the right final position, one multiplier would have to be scaled by 256, so wouldn't fit in an 8-bit input. So just vpshufb with 0x00FF00FF, 0x01FF01FF etc. to clear the odd elements, replicating into elements 0 and 2 of each u32, so you can do two 16-bit multiplies within each element.

@PeterCordes getting a bit lost. Could you show an example? Also, I cant seem to find a c# wrapper around the LoadBroadcast, so I am not sure it's supported in .Net https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.intrinsics.vector256?view=net-8.0

I would do it like that.
The main idea is loading 8 input bytes at a time, using the broadcast load instruction. Then selectively move and zero out bytes to expand these 8 bytes into 16 ushort numbers with the numbers scaled by 0x100 and duplicated. Then use 16-bit integer multiplications in two vectors, finally combine into a 32-bytes vector and store.
/// <summary>Create a pair of multipliers for _mm256_mulhi_epu16 instruction</summary>
static Vector256<ushort> makeMultipliers( byte low, byte high )
{
    // Compute multipliers with uint division
    uint a = low;
    uint b = high;
    a = ( a * 0x8000u + 254u ) / 255u;
    b = ( b * 0x8000u + 254u ) / 255u;
    // Create the pattern as uint scalar
    uint s = a | ( b << 16 );
    // Broadcast the uint, and bit cast the vector to short lanes
    return Vector256.Create( s ).AsUInt16();
}

// Permutation table which transform 4 bytes into 0A0A0B0B0C0C0D0D sequence of 16 bytes
static ReadOnlySpan<byte> permBytes => new byte[ 32 ]
{
    // First 16 byte slice uses bytes [ 0 .. 3 ]
    0xFF, 0, 0xFF, 0,  0xFF, 1, 0xFF, 1,  0xFF, 2, 0xFF, 2,  0xFF, 3, 0xFF, 3,
    // The second slice uses bytes [ 4 .. 7 ]
    0xFF, 4, 0xFF, 4,  0xFF, 5, 0xFF, 5,  0xFF, 6, 0xFF, 6,  0xFF, 7, 0xFF, 7,
};

[Benchmark]
public unsafe void GrayscaleToColor_Simd()
{
    Vector256<ushort> mul0 = makeMultipliers( _colorA, _colorG );
    Vector256<ushort> mul1 = makeMultipliers( _colorB, _colorR );

    Vector256<byte> perm;
    fixed( byte* ptr = permBytes )
        perm = Avx2.LoadVector256( ptr );
    Vector256<byte> blendMask = Vector256.Create( (ushort)0xFF00 ).AsByte();

    fixed( byte* bytePtr = _bytesGray )
    fixed( uint* pixelPtr = _pixelsRGBA )
    {
        byte* bytePtrEnd = bytePtr + ImageLength;
        byte* rsi = bytePtr;
        uint* rdi = pixelPtr;
        while( rsi < bytePtrEnd )
        {
            // Broadcast 8 bytes from memory
            Vector256<byte> grey32 = Avx2.BroadcastScalarToVector256( (ulong*)rsi ).AsByte();
            rsi += 8;
            // Duplicate bytes, scaling ushort numbers by the factor of 0x100
            Vector256<ushort> grey16 = Avx2.Shuffle( grey32, perm ).AsUInt16();

            // Multiply 16-bit numbers, keeping the higher 16 bits of the products
            Vector256<ushort> low = Avx2.MultiplyHigh( grey16, mul0 );
            Vector256<ushort> high = Avx2.MultiplyHigh( grey16, mul1 );
            // Shift bits into correct location,
            // which is low byte for even lanes, high byte for odd ones
            low = Avx2.ShiftRightLogical( low, 7 );
            high = Avx2.ShiftLeftLogical( high, 1 );

            // Combine into a single vector, and store
            Avx2.BlendVariable( low.AsByte(), high.AsByte(), blendMask )
                .AsUInt32().Store( rdi );
            rdi += 8;
        }
    }
}

By the way, you have an interesting numerical issue in your formula. When you do (byte)((value * _colorR) >> 8); you will never get 255 on output. Even when both input bytes are 255, you will only get 254 in the result.
That’s why I have used different math there. The rounding is less than ideal in my version because the optimal one would require twice as many multiplications in the loop: first to apply the input scaling, another one to divide by 255. Still, at least 0xFF input scaling seems to result in the original color.
Update: The idea behind the algorithm is following. The complete expression we need to compute for these numbers is grey * c / 255 which can be viewed as grey * mul where mul is a fractional number ≤ 1.0. Instead of doing floating-point math, my implementation computes that expression with a few cheap integer math instructions.
The _mm256_mulhi_epu16 instruction computes the following expression for each pair of ushort numbers: ( a * b ) >> 16
Note that instruction can’t scale input numbers by 100% because doing so would require b to be 0x10000 however that number doesn’t fit in ushort, it requires at least 17 bits.
The next best thing is scaling by up to 50%, because a 50% scaling would require b = 0x8000 which fits in the ushort lanes just fine, and then using bits [ 7 .. 14 ] of the output ushort lanes.
The makeMultipliers function computes two of these scaling coefficients and makes a vector of [ c0, c1 ] ushort numbers replicated over the complete vector. We call it twice because we need 4 of them, one of each channel of the output image.
Overall, my version does the following math to these bytes:
static byte computeColor( byte grey, byte component )
{
    // Computed by makeMultipliers outside of the loop
    uint c32 = component;
    c32 = ( c32 * 0x8000u + 254u ) / 255u;
    ushort c16 = (ushort)c32;

    // Computed by moving bytes by 1 with Avx2.Shuffle, which inserts zero bytes
    ushort grey16 = (ushort)( (ushort)grey << 8 );

    // Computed by Avx2.MultiplyHigh
    ushort res = (ushort)( ( (uint)c16 * grey16 ) >> 16 );

    // Computed by bitwise shifts and byte extracts
    return (byte)( res >> 7 );
}


You're loading with vpmovzxbd and then shuffling with vpshufb?  It would be more efficient to vpbroadcastq / vpshufb to get the same grey16 result (with some 0x80 bytes in the shuffle mask to create zeros), because 4/8/16-byte broadcast-loads are just a single uop for the load port, unlike vpmovzxbd which is load + ALU and doesn't even micro-fuse on Intel so 2 uops for the front-end.  (Or load with vbroadcasti128 and shuffle two different ways to get two grey16 results.)

@PeterCordes Seems on my computer the performance is equal. Still, updated the answer because it seems it’s won’t harm the performance on AMD, while improving on Intel.

@Soonts could you explain the code in makeMultipliers please? maybe in the comments?

@creativergk Sure, see the update
